# Mat Menu in Angular doesn't work properly in Firefox on mobile devices

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firefox, angular-material

I am implementing a nested mat menu in Angular. It works just fine on the desktop view, both on Chrome and on Firefox. But on mobile view on Firefox the submenus are being stacked on each other if I click on more than one button in the mat menu:

[Picture of unwanted behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohprO.png)

[Wanted behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Nmi.gif)

Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-toolbar-menu-yxf667?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Is it a known issue of Firefox /mat-menu? Or do I need to implement the behaviour for mobile view using (touchstart) and (touchend) or something?

Thanks